# Actions Runner issue, unable to download any version of Python

Tags: python, action, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

Every time I try to run a workflow in GitHub Actions I run into an issue installing Python. I have to run this self hosted runner on windows, on my own PC. I run it with full admin privileges every time. I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Here is an example with Python 11. I have tried so many different versions. I am running 3.12.1, which I have tested and does not work. I have to create a new folder each time after destroying the previous actions runner. Any thoughts?

```
  Version 3.11 was not found in the local cache
  Version 3.11 is available for downloading
  Download from "https://github.com/actions/python-versions/releases/download/3.11.7-7098196908/python-3.11.7-win32-x64.zip"
  Extract downloaded archive
  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop' ; try { Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem } catch { } ; [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('C:\Users\jorda\actions-runner\_work\_temp\36383fb1-ebad-446f-8b18-09c33c08fd93', 'C:\Users\jorda\actions-runner\_work\_temp\be064470-037b-412c-aff9-30ad947a6345')"
  Execute installation script
  Check if Python hostedtoolcache folder exist...
  
  Create Python toolcache folder
  
  Check if current Python version is installed...
  
  No Python3.11.* found
  
  Remove registry entries for Python 3.11(x64)...
  
  Create Python 3.11.7 folder in C:\Users\jorda\actions-runner\_work\_tool\Python
  
  Copy Python binaries to C:\Users\jorda\actions-runner\_work\_tool\Python\3.11.7\x64
  
  Install Python 3.11.7 in C:\Users\jorda\actions-runner\_work\_tool\Python...
    Error: Error happened during Python installation
      At C:\Users\jorda\actions-runner\_work\_temp\be064470-037b-412c-aff9-30ad947a6345\setup.ps1:127 char:5
      +     Throw "Error happened during Python installation"
      Error: +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Error happened ...on installation:String) [], RuntimeException
          + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Error happened during Python installation
      Error: The process 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' failed with exit code 1
```